# "Building to" — idiom or typo?

Tags: meaning, idioms

The title of [this article](http://www.ign.com/articles/2012/06/01/building-to-new-super-mario-bros) is "Building to New Super Mario Bros."

Is "building to" a typo or an idiom? What does it mean if it's not a typo? I've never come across that phrase before.

Comment: Of course, but in this case the phrase doesn't make any sense (to me).

Comment: The article title is actually: "Building to **New** Super Mario Bros." The hype is on for the name game. They're building up the anticipation of gamers.

Comment: Whoops, fixed. It still doesn't make sense to me, though.

Comment: The article is about two new Mario games, so it's obviously a typo. It should have been "Building **two** New Super Mario Bros."

Comment: At this point you should explain why that phrase doesn't make sense for you.

Comment: -1, but I cannot downvote your poor question. I hope that others people can do this.

Comment: You're right that this turned out to be a pretty stupid and embarrassing question, but somehow I just couldn't make any sense of the sentence at the time. Thanks for your help and apologies for wasting your time. Feel free to close or delete the question now.

Comment: @itsame, I really do not think it is a typo with, as you suggest, "to" being used when the writer meant "two." *Building to,* I think, references all that went before to get to the point where these new games can be released. And, as you saw, the article recaps each of the games between the original and the ones to be released and reviews the evolution of the Mario games that has resulted in the new games. The company used each of the past games, building upon past successes, to bring the new games to market.

Comment: I agree completely with @JLG since one can be "building to" something.  You can build to a climax, you can build to success, etc.  So when you consider the context of the article, it makes perfect sense to have the title that it does.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a typo for "Building *up* to Super Mario Bros".

Edit (credit Noah): or from "Building *on* Super Mario Bros".

Comment: That's what I thought, too.

Comment: @RégisRoux, I don't know if you meant to be offensive, but offense could be taken by saying someone isn't worth your consideration. And please do see the thread of comments above.

Comment: @jeffsahol- Could it also be something like *building on*, like this episode is built on the previous one. In this case Super Mario acting as an object(e.g, building to mario).  Just a wild thought.

Comment: I think "building to" is often used instead of "building up to" ... see here http://googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=building+up+to+the+goal&word2=building+to+the+goal